# Issues installing Custom Ubuntu after apt updates

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, chroot

I have been attempting to build a standard environment which uses Ubuntu 14.04 along with some additional packages and have made up a quick script to update apt and install the packages I require. Using Cubic I load the latest iso and enter the chroot environment.

If I just copy my update script into chroot (under folder /share), not change anything else and then use unetbootin to put the iso onto a flash drive, once I install onto the laptop everything works as intended. If I run my script which modifies the sources.list file, updates apt and installs a number of packages, then I start having issues.

My first issue using Ubuntu 16.04.3 was on installation I would get an error saying that grub-efi-amd64-signed was unable to be installed to /target/. Boot-repair wouldn't work to fix this issue.

I updated my original iso to Ubuntu 16.04.4 and again if I didn't make any changes it would work as intended, if I updated apt and installed the additional packages it would appear to install properly but on reboot I am taken to GNU GRUB version2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17 (Minimal BASH-like line editing).

As my systems will be offline, I cannot connect to the internet to download during installation and being able to use CUBIC to preinstall the additional packages is a godsend.

I am not sure if there is something I am doing wrong or if the updates being applied are breaking something in the chroot environment which is being transferred to the installed environment.

My script contains the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -eu -o pipefail # fail on error, debug all lines

    # update the sources.list file

    cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list

    # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

    # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
    # newer versions of the distribution.
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

    ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
    ## distribution.
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

    ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
    ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
    ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    ## security team.
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

    ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    # deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

    ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
    ## 'partner' repository.
    ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
    # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
    # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
    EOF

    # Update APT and upgrade all packages
    apt update && apt upgrade -y

    # Install pre-determined software
    apt install aptitude k3b dc3dd dcfldd minicom samba virt-manager virtualbox p7zip-full p7zip-rar filezilla bless gcp tree pv grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed shim shim-signed -y

    # Remove guest login
    cat <<EOF > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
    [SeatDefaults]
    user-session=ubuntu
    greeter-session=unity-greeter
    allow-guest=false
    EOF

    # Change user libvirt-qemu (virt-manager user) show it doesn't show in greeter
    usermod -u 499 libvirt-qemu

    # Download aptitude packages to enable operation on generic hardware profiles
    aptitude install --download-only initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core linux-firmware linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic init-system-helpers intltool-debian linux-base linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-40 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-40-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-signed-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-signed-image-4.10.0-40-generic linux-signed-image-generic-hwe-16.04 usb-modeswitch-data
```

The aptitude packages are there to support various hardware profiles that this iso might be installed on.

Hoping this is something simple that I have missed or need to remove to make this work.

Thanks for all your help.

John

Comment: Well I am not sure what happened, but after starting again and running the script in sections, everything seems to have resolved. I have modified the 'remove guest login' as this is not the best method for this but other than that not much else was changed.

Answer (score 0):

All fixed, took the time to divide the script up and run manually, then tested with a slightly modified script and all seems to be working. Not sure what the root cause was but suspect modification of the lightdm.conf file, along with removal of the shim and efi-grub packages has fixed the issue.